# check correctly checkboxes from mysql (php)

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with checkboxes.
I have some project they you can filter at categories.
So the problem is when you want edit a project that automatic the correct category are checked.
[here you see a project but the categories are empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MleU.png)

In mine databank I use is a combo table - one to insert my categories and one for the project and there I have a combo table from.

Here you see my code for display the `checkboxes` and select for editing so now I looking for some help, for checked the correctly `checkbox` that belongs to that project.

```
<div id="categoriefilter">
  <?php     
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `categories` ORDER BY `id` ASC";
  $cats = DB::getResult($sql);
  foreach($cats as $cat){
  ?>
  <label>
      <input name="cat[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $cat['id']; ?>" >
      <?php echo $cat['categorienaam']; ?>
  </label>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly. You need 3 tables here

Table1 : `projects` `id, name, ...`
Table2: `categories` `id, name, ...`
Table3: `projects_categories` `project_id, category_id, ...`

The third table is needed to store the categories which are selected for projects

And inside your project page
You need to do the followings:

1. Select your project by its id
2. Select categories
3. Select categories related to the project ( from Table3 )

---

Here is example ( this is not a working code, just a showcase )

```
//  your project
$project = DB::getResult("SELECT * FROM project WHERE id = :id "); // <== id here

// list of categories
$categories = DB::getResult("SELECT * FROM categories ");

// list of categories for this project
$project_categories = DB::getResult("SELECT category_id FROM projects_categories WHERE project_id = :project_id ");
$project_categories = (array) $project_categories; // in case DB::getResult is not array

<?php
    foreach($categories as $category) :
?>
<label>
    <input name="cat[]" 
        <?php if(in_array($category['id'], $project_categories)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>
        type="checkbox" value="<?= $category['id']; ?>" >
    <?php echo $category['name']; ?>
</label>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: now i saw that he insert only one cat , when i select more as one he take the last and show also one

Comment: @jorik I didn't get what you said but you have to make a loop for your `cat[]` input and insert all ids in database. if it's still unclear please update your post to know what is exactly the problem you faced

Answer (score 0):

I'm not down voter. If you knew your problem, you probably mightn't post the question.

You don't include the details code. However for the part as far as I'm understanding,

You should run database `UPDATE` query inside `foreach` loop. You don't need to keep the `html input` inside the loop.

```
  <?php    
  // check if checkbox is checked 
  if (!empty($_POST['cat'])){   
  foreach($_POST['cat'] as $cat){
  // run update query here
  $sql = "UPDATE `categories` SET `categorienaam` = $whatever WHERE `id` = $cat";
  $result = DB::getResult($sql);
  }
  }
  ?>
```

```html
  <label>
      <input name="cat[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $RowOfApplicableSelectQuery['id']; ?>" >
  </label>
```

`$RowOfApplicableSelectQuery` comes from the query that you are using to fetch and display your record primarily.

I hope it gives you a clue about what are you looking for.

Comment: its not a good idea to query inside loops. you can use mysql `in ( ids with comma separated ) ` to grab records and loop through those records

Comment: @pars, Just showed him the basic way about how the thing should be. It can be done in many ways.